How to pass data between files in Webots?
I want to pass data from a robot controller to the supervisor, but I can't seem to find a working solution.
Both the codes are in Matlab. The controller should send a boolean to the supervisor when it encounters an object.
I tried TCP/IP and global values but none of them seem to work:
Controller code:
data_to_send = false; 

client_socket = tcpip('localhost', 12345);
fopen(client_socket);

while true
fwrite(client_socket, data_to_send, 'boolean');
end

fclose(client_socket);

Supervisor code:
server_socket = tcpip('0.0.0.0', 12345, 'NetworkRole', 'server');

fopen(server_socket);

while true 

while ~server_socket.BytesAvailable pause(0.1); end

received_data = fread(server_socket, server_socket.BytesAvailable, 'boolean');

disp(['Received data from the controller: ', num2str(received_data)]);

end 

fclose(server_socket);


There are mainly two options to make controllers communicate with each other in Webots:

use the Emitter/Receiver mechanism to send data from one robot controller the other one.
use the Robot.data field to store the data to share and read it in the other controller program using the Supervisor API.

Alternatively, you may also use any standard inter-process communication (IPC) mechanism, such as files, sockets, shared memory, pipes, etc. But these are not specific to Webots.
See also this answer.
